# Kill detached screen session

Tags: linux, kill, gnu-screen

I learned from somewhere a detached screen can be killed by

```
screen -X -S [session # you want to kill] kill
```

where [session # you want to kill] can be gotten from

```
screen -ls
```

But this doesn't work. Anything wrong? What's the correct way?

Comment: "somewhere" is not always a good source of information. Try "man screen".

Comment: The correct command is `screen -S sessionname -p 0 -X quit`

Comment: killall -# screen [# = number of screens you want to kill]

Comment: I simply use **exit**

Comment: CTRL + D when in screen is the easiest command.

Answer (score 1266, accepted):

"kill" will only kill one screen window. To "kill" the complete session, use `quit`.

#### Example

```
$ screen -X -S [session # you want to kill] quit
```

For dead sessions use:
    $ screen -wipe

Comment: type 'exit' (without the quotes) in ubuntu :P

Comment: `exit` works but needs to be typed into each screen that was opened. `quit` does not even work

Comment: @kapad actually quit works if you write it inline -X -S pid/sockname quit

Comment: on OSX entering `screen -X quit` on any terminal terminates all active sessions

Comment: 'quit' worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ctrl + D also works

Comment: Exit and quit and Ctrl-D do not work.  poweroff, reboot, init 6 will work, as will pkill, but with severe caveats. Try and imagine doing this remotely with Ansible or plink. You can also connect to a process running inside the unattachable screen and end that (Minecraft by rcon, say).

Answer (score 497):

You can kill a detached session which is not responding within the screen session by doing the following.

1. Type `screen -list` to identify the detached screen session.

   ```
   ~$ screen -list  
       There are screens on:  
            20751.Melvin_Peter_V42  (Detached)
   ```

   Note: `20751.Melvin_Peter_V42` is your session id.
2. Get attached to the detached screen session

   ```
   screen -r 20751.Melvin_Peter_V42
   ```
3. Once connected to the session press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then type `:quit`

Comment: you can just use screen -r 20751 without the full name

Comment: or: Ctrl + a, k

Comment: @laffuste 's comment worked for me, but `quit` and `:quit` lead to `command not found` on my remote Linux server (perhaps differences between versions of the OS or screen are to blame)

Comment: once attached to the screen, `exit` also works

Answer (score 145):

**List screens:**

```
screen -list
```

**Output:**

```
There is a screen on:
23536.pts-0.wdzee       (10/04/2012 08:40:45 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

**Kill screen session:**

```
screen -S 23536 -X quit
```

Comment: 'screen -ls' also works. ;)

Answer (score 113):

It's easier to kill a session, when some meaningful name is given:

```
//Creation:
screen -S some_name proc
// Kill detached session
screen -S some_name -X quit
```

Comment: Why `screen -S` and not `screen -r`?

Comment: This answer uses the name of the session, which is way more convenient than looking up the ID.  Thank You!

Answer (score 43):

You can just go to the place where the screen session is housed and run:

```
 screen -ls
```

which results in

```
 There is a screen on:
         26727.pts-0.devxxx      (Attached)
 1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-xxx. <------ this is where the session is.
```

And just remove it:

1. ```
   cd /tmp/uscreens/S-xxx
   ```
2. ```
   ls
   ```
3. ```
   26727.pts-0.devxxx
   ```
4. ```
   rm 26727.pts-0.devxxx
   ```
5. ```
   ls
   ```

The `uscreens` directory will not have the `26727.pts-0.devxxx` file in it anymore. Now to make sure just type this:

`screen -ls`

and you should get:

> No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-xxx.

Comment: This is the only solution that will work if the screen is "stuck", ie. not dead, but cannot be attached to.

Comment: This helped me when the screen was utterly locked, but I did need to find and kill the actual process as well. `ps aux | grep screen` found the pid and I issued a `kill` to remove it. Depending on what you had running in your screen, you may have temp files and locks to clean up as well.

Answer (score 29):

```
screen -wipe
```

Should clean all ***dead*** screen sessions.

Comment: What means dead? not running any program?

Comment: @ShihaoXu Dead means the session is unreachable and on localhost (socket connection is broken). - see https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

Answer (score 23):

add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias cleanscreen="screen -ls | tail -n +2 | head -n -2 | awk '{print $1}'| xargs -I{} screen -S {} -X quit"
```

Then use `cleanscreen` to clean all screen session.

Comment: A simple one-liner: `screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Worked a treat, but had to modify it slightly to work on OSX:

`screen -ls | tail +2 | head -2 | awk '{print $1}'| xargs -I{} screen -S {} -X quit`

Comment: Slight improvement:-screen -ls | grep Attached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} screen -d {}

Answer (score 21):

For me a simple

```
exit
```

works.  This is from within the screen session.

Comment: also, ctrl+a `:quit`

Comment: also, ctrl+a, then K

Comment: Or just CTRL+D within a screen

Answer (score 16):

To kill *all* detached screen sessions, include this function in your .bash_profile:

```
killd () {
for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]\{5\}')
do
screen -S "${session}" -X quit;
done
}
```

to run it, call `killd`

Comment: Sometimes it's not 5 digits, so i use:
killd () {
for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
do
screen -S "${session}" -X quit;
done
}

Answer (score 7):

```
== ISSUE THIS COMMAND
[xxx@devxxx ~]$ screen -ls


== SCREEN RESPONDS
There are screens on:
        23487.pts-0.devxxx      (Detached)
        26727.pts-0.devxxx      (Attached)
2 Sockets in /tmp/uscreens/S-xxx.


== NOW KILL THE ONE YOU DONT WANT
[xxx@devxxx ~]$ screen -X -S 23487.pts-0.devxxx kill


== WANT PROOF?
[xxx@devxxx ~]$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        26727.pts-0.devxxx      (Attached)
1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-xxx.
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just remove the socket, not kill the process behind it?

Comment: Is this method is risky from the point of view of creation of zomby processes ?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, while in your screen session all you have to do is type **exit**

This will kill the shell session initiated by the screen, which effectively terminates the screen session you are on.

No need to bother with screen session id, etc.