# Kill all detached screen sessions

Tags: session, batch-processing, gnu-screen

When I execute `screen -ls`, I see the following. How can I kill all the detached sessions?

```
There are screens on:
        84918.ttys002.ros-mbp   (Detached)
        84944.ttys008.ros-mbp   (Detached)
        84970.ttys013.ros-mbp   (Attached)
        84998.ttys002.ros-mbp   (Detached)
        85024.ttys002.ros-mbp   (Detached)
5 Sockets in /var/folders/86/062qtcyx2rxbnmn8mtpkyghs0r0r_z/T/.screen.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill detached screen session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509677/kill-detached-screen-session)

Comment: I've since switch to **tmux**, which is a better version of screen.

Answer (score 112):

`screen -ls | grep pts | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Kill **only Detached** screen sessions (credit @schatten):

`screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Good solution, thanks. But it also kills attached session.
I used this one  
    `screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Comment: @schatten Could you explain the working of the command separately per pipe?

Comment: @MusséRedi 
`screen -ls` – does not start a new screen, but lists all screen sessions; 

`grep Detached` – detached sessions are marked as 'Detached' in the previous output; 
`cut -d. -f1` - splits every string by "."(-d.) and then select only the first part (-f1), this way we have only pid with possible leading spaces; 
`awk {print $1}` – it reads the input line and splits it by spaces, so basically in this case it just removes leading spaces; 
`xargs kill` – runs `kill` cmd with appended arguments from stdin, so for every line you would get a `kill <pid>`.

Comment: If you're on a Linux box, not Apple, you'll need `screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r kill` to prevent the command erroring if there are no current screens running (especially useful in bash scripts)

Answer (score 28):

Here's a solution that combines all the answers:  Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
killscreens () {
    screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
}
```

- this is a convenient function, easy to remember
- kills only the detached screens, to stop you from doing something dumb
- remember to open a new bash terminal or run `source .bashrc` to make `killscreens` available

*Thanks to @Rose Perrone, @Milind Shah, and @schatten*

Answer (score 11):

Include this function in your .bash_profile:

```
killd () {
    for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}')
    do
        screen -S "${session}" -X quit;
    done
}
```

To run it, call `killd`. This will kill all screen sessions, detached or not.

Comment: That should be `'[0-9]\{3,\}'`

Comment: Elegant solution, one that is goo dto haev

Answer (score 3):

Combining Edward Newell's and Rose Perrone's solutions into a more readable and "screen" like solution.

Add below to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

```
# function for killing all detached screen sessions
killds() {
    detached_sessions=$(screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}')
    for s in ${detached_sessions}
    do
        screen -S "${s}" -X quit;
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the screens are dead, use:

```
screen -wipe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'[0-9]\{3,\}'
```

in case of

```
There is a screen on:
20505.blabla    (03/05/2014 22:16:25)   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-blabla.
```

will match both 20505 and 2014, where quitting 2014 will return "No screen session found."

```
[0-9]\{3,\}\.\S*
```

might work.

I've always encountered pattern 20505.*name*, where *name* is either host name or session name if screen was launched with -S flag. Works on OS X and Debian, might not be universal.