# Kill Attached Screen in Linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I created a screen "myscreen" in linux and it stopped responding abruptly.  I closed the terminal and tried to reopen it.    "screen -ls" shows that the screen is Attached.  I tried the following commands but nothing responds.

```
screen -r myscreen
screen -D myscreen
screen -D -RR myscreen
screen -X -S myscreen quit
```

Any help to reattach to the screen or to kill the screen is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what screen is, but if it's a process, then kill -9?

Comment: I am not sure if screen is a process. But "kill -9" will kill the entire process.  But i want to kill the particular screen and leave the other screens uninterrupted.

Comment: Have you tried `screen -dr myscreen`?

Comment: tried "screen -dr myscreen" too

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
screen -X -S SCREENID kill
```

alternatively, you can use the following command

```
screen -S SCREENNAME -p 0 -X quit
```

You can view the list of the screen sessions by executing `screen -ls`

Comment: I notice the first command sequence only kills the last window if you have multiple windows open while the second actually kills the entire screen regardless of the number of windows.

Comment: Is there a possibility to delete all processes and clear up the screen?

Comment: Yeah sure and use either `pkill screen` or `killall screen`

Answer (score 22):

Create screen from Terminal:

```
screen -S <screen_name>
```

To see list of screens:

```
<screen -ls> or <screen -list>
```

To go to particular screen:

```
<screen -x screen_name>

<screen -r screen_name>
```

Inside screen

---

To Terminate screen:

```
give ctrl+d screen will get terminated
```

To Detach screen:

```
 give <ctrl+ad>or <screen -d >screen will get detached
```

To reattach screen:

```
screen -x <screen_name> or screen -r <screen_name>
```

To kill a screen from Terminal:

```
<screen -X -S screen_name quit>
```

or

```
<screen -X -S screen_name kill>
```

You can use screen_name or process_id to execute commands.

Comment: This is just a list of screen commands, not an answer to this specific question.

Comment: These list of commands helped me resolve my issue, thank you for posting

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me very well. Get the screen id via:

```
screen -r
```

or

```
screen -ls
```

then kill the screen: `kill -9 <screenID>`
it now becomes a dead screen,
then wipe it out with: `screen -wipe`

Answer (score 5):

From Screen User's [Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) ;

```
screen -d -r "screenName"
```

*Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Nost easy solution without loosing the screen session! Thanks!

Comment: what does that -d and -r do here ?

Comment: Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.

Answer (score 3):

To **kill a detached screen** use this from the terminal:

```
screen -X -S "SCEEN_NAME" quit
```

**If you are attached**, then use (from the terminal and inside the screen):

```
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to kill all existing sessions. take a look at [Kill all detached screen sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447131/kill-all-detached-screen-sessions)

to list all active sessions use 
screen -r

when listed, select with your mouse the session you are interested in and paste it. like this

screen -r

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your screen id has a pattern. Then you can use the following code to kill all the attached screen at once.

```
result=$(screen -ls | grep 'pattern_of_screen_id' -o)
for i in $result; 
do      
    `screen -X -S $i quit`;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually don't name my screen instances, so this might not be useful, but did you try `screen -r` without the 'myscreen' part?  usually for me, `screen -r` will show the PIDs of each screen then i can reattach with `screen -d -r <PID>`

Comment: Yes, that was the first command I tried.  but it didn't respond.  I tried to open as root user but the screen was not even detected for root user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the process id of the attached running screen.
I found it same as the session id which you can get by command:
`screen -ls`
And you can use following command to kill that process:
`kill [sessionId]` or
 `sudo kill [sessionId]`

Answer (score 0):

None of the `screen` commands were killing or reattaching the screen for me. Any `screen` command would just hang. I found another approach.

Each running screen has a file associated with it in:

`/var/run/screen/S-{user_name}`

The files in that folder will match the names of the screens when running the `screen -list`. If you delete the file, it kills the associated running screen (detached or attached).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow this procedure

If the screen is in detached state

```
screen -r "screenName"

exit
```

this will kill/ terminate the screen which you want to kill

If the screen is in attached state

```
screen -d -r "screenName"

exit
```

Answer (score -2):

For result find: [Click Here](http://www.catonmat.net/download/screen.cheat.sheet.pdf)

Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes, typically interactive shells. There is a scrollback history buffer for each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows the user to move text regions between windows.

Comment: This is not very helpful: it's just part of the man page and a cheat sheet wich the OP has certainly read.