# GNU screen command not showing status bar

Tags: unix, gnu, gnu-screen

I am new to GNU screen command. I created .screenrc file in my home directory and added below two lines([source](http://sourceopen.com/2014/06/09/gnu-screen-status-bar-tips-tricks-basics/)) to display the status bar.
    `caption always`
    `caption string "%{= bW}%3n %{y}%t %{-}%= %{m}%H%?%{-} -- %{c}%l%?%{-} -- %D %M %d %{y}%c"`

but I am not seeing the status bar(after entering into screen mode).
When I run `source .screenrc`, I am getting error `"-bash: caption: command not found"`.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that, I already started screen and then added the file `.screenrc` in my home directory, but active screens are not recognizing the `.screenrc` file.
so I [killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509677/kill-detached-screen-session) all active screen sessions and then stated new screen session (`screen`).  Now I am able to see the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot do `soruce .screenrc`, since that tries to run the file with bash (or whatever is in the first line if you have #!/some/shellorprogram).

I'm not sure why you are not seeing the status bar, but the source command is a red herring.

Can you try something simpler with the caption, and maybe even something static to see if the syntax is right and it's the format string that is breaking?

Something like

`caption always`
`caption string "test caption"`

On my Ubuntu server the test caption works, so it's probably your format string.  Build it piece by piece to find the busted part.

The other one works, too.  Where are you putting your screenrc file?

`ls -al ~/.screenrc`

Comment: I have file in my home directory<br>
`$ls -al ~/.screenrc`<br>
`-rwxr--r-- 1 amaresh ppusers 152 Jul 21 22:14 /x/home/amaresh/.screenrc`<br>
`$`<br>

Comment: I tried with simple string as you suggested, but not working.