# Unable to source .screenrc, it says command not found

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gnu-screen, screenrc

I am trying to get tabs in my screen using .screenrc, but while sourcing, it says command not found. It is on ubuntu14.04. I have screen installed. I can create screen but just unable to get tabs details using screenrc.

```
machine:~$ cat .screenrc
caption always caption string "test caption"
hardstatus string "%{= g} %{= w}%-Lw%{=r}%n%f* %t%{-}%+LW"

machine:~$ source .screenrc
caption: command not found 
hardstatus: command not found
```

Can someone let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: `.screenrc` is not a shell script; it's a configuration file for the `screen` program.

Comment: Yes, but to get its effect, we need to source it. Without that when you create screen, you won't see tabs or screen configurations taking effect.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites superuser.com OR unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: ^^^ Number 1 search result for this question - an answer would have been nice

Comment: This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538367/gnu-screen-command-not-showing-status-bar

You need to start new screen session with another session name.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to source .screenrc

The modified settings will be applied to any new screen sessions you start. They will not be applied to existing screen sessions.

Comment: This question is not about programming and should be closed, do not reply.